# Azure Data Lake Count All Items

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

Is there a way to recursively count all items on an Azure Data lake Store instance?

When assigning permissions, all files and folders are cycled through.. but there isn't much in the way of knowing how far you have gone through the process.

Knowing how many files in total would be pretty helpful!

I got this far:

```
$m = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem 'batadlspdnetpdtest01' -Path '/' | measure
$m.Count
```

and then started looking for a switch to also check children...

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is sound, but there's not a built-in way to get the list of items recursively. There's a bit of code you can write on top of the cmdlets to do this very thing, by looking at each item and recursively listing if the item is a directory.

[Here's some sample code that accomplishes this.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/master/Samples/PowerShell/Get-ItemsRecursive.ps1)